# Specifying a custom data directory in brightway2

Tags: python

Although specifying a custom data directory in brightway2 is not the standard, some people may still need to do so. One way of doing this is to set the BRIGHTWAY_DIR path variable to this custom directory (see here: https://docs.brightwaylca.org/faq.html#setting-brightway2-dir-in-a-virtual-environment), but this needs to happen BEFORE executing a python script.

So instead of setting the directory path (e.g. for Windows) like this beforehand:
set BRIGHTWAY2_DIR=C:/.../MyDataDirectory

Is there also a possibility of setting/changing the brightway directory from within python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.putenv?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
from brightway2 import projects
from bw2data.project import ProjectDataset, create_database


def switch_directory(dirpath):
    assert os.path.isdir(dirpath)
    projects._base_data_dir = dirpath
    projects._base_logs_dir = os.path.join(dirpath, "logs")
    os.mkdir(projects._base_logs_dir)
    projects.db.close()
    projects.db = create_database(
        os.path.join(projects._base_data_dir, "projects.db"), 
        [ProjectDataset]
    )
    projects.set_current("default")
```

It uses basically the same framework as the [test runner](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/eab9a630394eef70ff6774d7670cde8d621b1762/bw2data/project.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#project.py-253).

Comment: thanks! This works if I comment the os.mkdir(projects._base_logs_dir) line (the directory already exists, which is asserted by the assert statement);